# How to initialize a variable of data type const WCHAR*

Tags: c++, gdi

`GdipCreateFontFamilyFromName` first parameter expects a `const WCHAR*`, how I could initialize the value of `opt.fontName` with it?

```
struct GDImDrawText
{
    HWND hWnd;
    ARGB fontColor;
    int fontSize;
    int fontStyle = 0;
    WCHAR* fontName;  // <--- Do i need to use another data type? which?
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w;
    int h;
};  

//...

GDI gdip;
GDImDrawText opt;

opt.fontColor = 0xffffff;
opt.fontSize = 14; 
opt.fontName = L"Tahoma"; // <--- ???
opt.hWnd = hWnd; 
opt.x = 20;

gdip.mDrawText(g, opt);

//...

void GDI::mDrawText(GpGraphics* g, GDImDrawText opt)
{
    GpFontFamily* fontFamily;
    GdipCreateFontFamilyFromName(opt.fontName, 0, &fontFamily);
    //...
}
```

Do I need to modify the declaration of `fontName` into the struct?

Comment: LPCWSTR fontName;  Or if this code is old and has too many "quirks" like this then use Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > "Conformance Mode" = No

Comment: The literal `L"Tahoma"` is const, so doesn't match the pointer type. You can get a non-const string as `wchar_t Tahoma[] = L"Tahoma";` and then use the array name as the parameter. (And WCHAR is just an ancient name from before wchar_t was a proper type, nothing magic).

Answer (score 0):

`WCHAR` is a wide character normally representing 16 bit instead of the default 8 bit of a `char`. It is used e.g to represent encoding standards like UTF-16 which can not be encoded with only 8 bits (like ASCII).

You initialized your `wide char array` correctly by specifying it with the `L` in front of the string. This tells the compiler that the string is in fact a `wide char array` instead of a "normal" `char array`.